# "method saveas of object _workbook failed with excel 2010 but not with excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I think it is probably a small mistake but I get the following message with excel 2010 "method saveas of object _workbook failed" but not with 2016 (works smoothly).

```
wb4.SaveAs FileName:="M:\Sites\Braine\GTSO\Supply Chain\GSC Reporting & Analytics\CDP-OMP\CDP\1. Sales & Stock Monthly import\" & year2 & "\" & bMonth2 & "\Workfile" & Date & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
```

Any ideas?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try swapping out the `M:` for the UNC equivalent.

Comment: You are using `Date` in filename, maybe it give an unaccepted character in file name like "/"

Comment: Was the date indeed, apparently 2016 doesn't have a problem with that but 2010 does. Thank you for your reply and the solution!

Answer (score 1):

You are using Date in filename, maybe it give an unaccepted character in file name like "/" (Fadi Comment)